# Meteor simpleSchema prevent field updates

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

Is it possible to specify that a field is not updateable using the schema itself rather than defining it in an allow/deny rule?

I am wondering because I use a quickform to allow users to edit their user details based on the users document (accounts package) and I want to prevent them from being able to change the verified state for their email address.

A rule based on user roles would be great to only allow admins and meteor itself to change the state of this field.

I'd be hoping for something like this:

```
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
        allowRoles: ['admin','system'] // this does not exist
    },
```

regards, Chris

Comment: I don't think it's possible directly from autoform. 
Check this package ongoworks:security it permits to define the field you allow/deny to update and it's more userfriendly than allow/deny rule.

Comment: Thanks. Just had a look at the package and I will use it in the future. Unfortunately it only works on top level properties. I can therefore not use it for emails.$.verified right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few different options.

To prevent anyone from updating a field, you can set the denyUpdate field in the flag definition (requires aldeed:collection2)

```
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
    denyUpdate: true
},
```

To allow it to be updated by admin's only, you could try a custom validator that checks the userId to see if it is an admin (example requires aldeed:collection2 and alanning:roles)

```
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
    custom: function() {
      if ( this.isSet && this.isUpdate &&  !Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, "admin") ) {
        return "unauthorized";
      }
    }
},
```

You'd probably also want to define a message for the "unauthorized" validation error.

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
   "unauthorized" : "You do not have permission to update this field"
})
```

This will display an error to the user if they try to change the field.

Alternately, you could simply unset the value provided by non-admin users and allow the rest of the update to go ahead.

```
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
    autoValue: function() {
      if ( !Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, "admin") ) {
        this.unset();
      }
    }
},
```